# Is there a way for me to schedule a 302 redirect in IIS or web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have some websites that need to be set to 302 redirect at midnight of a specific date. I understand that I can setup the redirects through IIS or through web.config for the site, but both of those would require me to make the change by hand at midnight as I understand it. Is there any way for me to setup ahead of time for the redirect to begin at a future date?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a redirect in the global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DateTime dateToRedirect = new DateTime(2015, 4, 1);
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    if(DateTime.Now > dateToRedirect)
    {
        if(...) // Conditional code for setting which pages get redirected
        {
            string newUrl = "http://www.example.com";
            context.Response.Redirect(newUrl);
        }
    }
}
```